# Formulating my div objects in such a way that it resembles a sine wave

Tags: javascript

So the basic idea is that I have an array of 8 div rectangles with a width of 30 px and a random height through Math. rand. Right now I'm trying to arrange them such that they form a sine wave pattern. I know I have to use Math.sin somewhere, but I have no clue as to go about it. Any help with this issue will be greatly appreciated. Here is what I have so far:

```
var divArr = new Array();

for(i = 0; i < 8; i++){

 //var rand_numX = Math.floor((100-19)*Math.random()) + 20;
 var rand_numY = Math.floor((100-19)*Math.random()) + 20;
 divArr[i] = OS.dom.add_element('div', view, {position: 'absolute', width:'30px', height: rand_numY+'px', 'background-color': '#000000'});

 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example:

```
for(var i = 0; i <= 7; i++) {
    var yPos = 10 + 10 * Math.sin((i / 7) * 2 * Math.PI);
    var div = $('<div/>').text('*').css({position: 'absolute', left: (i * 10) + 'px', top: yPos + 'px'});
    $('body').append(div);
}
```

See it in action: http://jsfiddle.net/cJPsT/1/

`Math.sin((i / 7) * 2 * Math.PI)` is the important part. It calculates the y position for the wave. The `10 + 10 *` just offsets the curve so it's not a the very top and makes it bigger.

Dealing with the random heights is left your job. But now you know how to draw a simple sine wave so I'm sure you'll figure it out.

Comment: Thnaks for the fast reply. Quick question though, what are you trying to accomplish with (i/7) * 2? I assume that after you multiply it with PI, you get the y position, but could you explain a bit more if you can

Comment: What @WCV did was he divided sinus function period by 7 to give you 8 points on single sinus loop which is equal to 2 * Math.PI that's why he is multiplying it with i / 7 though if you want to include the random height you'll have to compensate the top position by negative half of the height I believe

Comment: @Tom Tu: Ok, that makes a bit of sense. How would I go about incorporating my random height to my sin, because all that comes to mind is adding it to 1/2 yPos

Comment: @WCV well it all depends on how you are positioning the elements but having `yPos - 0.5 * height` should be ok - that is if you want middle of the boxes to form the sinusoid - if you want to have them in a way that bottoms of the boxes form it you'd have to substract full height of the box `ypos -/+ height you could also tweak the `10` value which multiplies the Math.sin formula to increase/decrease the amplitude of sinusoid.

Comment: @Tom Tu: Yeah I'm going about it so that the bottom left of the box forms the sinusoid. Probably means i need to tweak (i * 10) for the left of the div as well, or is that not necessary? I apologize for the excess questioning, i'm new to javascript and programming so I'm learning the fundamentals

Comment: @WCV i * 10 means that it will put elements 10px away from each other - you should use your elements width in place of that (`i * width`)

Comment: @Tom Tu Alright so right now, i have a sine wave of my div boxes but I having issues with positioning. Pretty much, I'm trying to get the formation right such that the wave hits the bottom-left and top-right of the box, which i having issues accomplishing. The following is the code(http://terpconnect.umd.edu/~chipva/hworld.js) and picture(http://terpconnect.umd.edu/~chipva/sinewave_div.PNG).

Comment: Ok so, right now the wave is still it a bit off but its getting there. How would I sit up function so that it grabs the width and based on that, it's sets the height, as well as the positions of each div in so that bottom-left and top-right of the divs make up the wave?